# how to pass parameter value into query in spring boot for join column?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, joincolumn

[This is the code for bill entity, i have variable of group and the table name is gid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvgY3.png)

[This is the bill repository, i have tried both the commented and the non commented part, both are not working. It says not matching types.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnBzg.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this case [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpt7e.png the first query cannot work because you are returning a different data type than the one indicated by the function

And in the second case [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DuZ6.png you are using a like operator for a Long data type, which is not possible.

Try something like this:

```
@Query(value="Select b from Bill where b.group.g_id =:gid")
List<Bill> findByGid(@Param("gid") Long gid);
```

I also don't understand why you try to make the union with **g_id** instead of with **group.id**

**I really think the code you need is this:**

```
@Query(value="Select b from Bill where b.group.id =:gid")
List<Bill> findByGid(@Param("gid") Long gid);
```